# Exclude column in certain rows - SQL / Asp.Net

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I'm wanting to change some code which was written for me. I would like to omit displaying the hyperlink where tblResults.videoLink=''

The hyperlink is displayed in the table as "Video Link" so people can click on it. I only want the words/hyperlink "Video Link" to appear in the row where people have entered one.

The code is Microsoft SQL but is written in the ASPX file. The back end is VB but there's VB is pretty much empty.. The ASPX file handles everything...

```
    <h1>Recent Results</h1>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlMyWishes" runat="server">

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSWishes" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT tblResults.wishID, tblResults.Player1AccountID, tblResults.Player2AccountID, tblResults.Player1Result, tblResults.Player2Result, tblResults.venue, tblResults.potSize, tblResults.player1Name, tblResults.player2Name, tblResults.videoLink, tblResults.date FROM tblResults ORDER BY tblResults.date DESC">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="gdvWishes" width="100%" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" DataKeyNames="wishID" DataSourceID="DSWishes" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="True">
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
            <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="player1Name" HeaderText="Player 1" />      
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Result">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblP1" Text='<%# Eval("player1Result").ToString %>' runat="server" Visible="true">
                        </asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblVs" Text=" - " runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblP2" Text='<%# Eval("player2Result").ToString %>' runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="17%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="player2Name" HeaderText="Player 2" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="potSize" HeaderText="Pot" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="venue" HeaderText="Venue" />
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hypVideoLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("videoLink").ToString %>'>Video Link</asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sub like below, call it after the code that fills your `GridView` with data.

```
Private Sub HideBlankURLs()
    For Each r As GridViewRow in gdvWishes.Rows
        If r.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then //Execute the code only for datarow, excluding footer and header
            Dim hypURL As HyperLink
            hypURL = r.Cells(5).FindControl("hypVideoLink") //Goes to the column of VideoURL, index 5 is counting from 0 to 5
            If hypURL.NavigateURL = "" Then //Checks if the URL is blank, if it is then hide the hyperlink control
                hypURL.Visible = False
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

This will loop through all the rows and look for the control in that column, check if navigate URL is blank, then hide that control.

NOTE: Replace the (//) with single quote (') because SO reads it as text enclosing character rather than a comment.

Comment: You're an absolute superstar.. Works perfectly thank you. You can see it here.. http://www.poolmatchup.com/results.aspx